# Microsoft Visual Studio c# кнопка текст ссылка

Tags: c#, winforms

пришёл за помощью и разъяснением,делаю для себя программу складского учёта,язык не много знаю с#,но не идеально.В visual studio воспользовался шаблоном (DataGridViev) в таблице есть как текст так и кнопка.Надо сделать так,чтобы в один столбик я вписывал ссылку на страницу запчасти,а столбик с кнопками считывал соответственную строчку с текстом(в которой я впишу ссылку )и открывал это в браузере.В интернете нашел только методы Linklabel и WebBrowser они не подходят,так как и таблица нужна и ссылку надо самому вписывать с программы,а не сразу в коде)

Comment: зачем так сложно, в формах же есть контрол что то типа Hyperlik или типа того, это прямо как ссылка выглядит, по нажатию выполняйте Process.Start(ваша ссылка) и система сама откроет её дефолтным браузером, подробнее [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/link-to-an-object-or-web-page-with-wf-linklabel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Можно ссылку и из кода вписать. С тем же LinkLabel через свойство `Text`. И как вам сказали выше, по клику выполнять `Process.Start(linkLabel1.Text)`